# Create QR code to app in market

Tags: android

How can I create a QR code to my app in the Android Market?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is really happening when you scan a qr code and it takes you to the android market is that the qr code just represents a url and the default android browser is opening and then recognizing the url as a market link and forwarding you to the market app.

You should be able to use a site like :

http://qrcode.kaywa.com/

To build a qrcode for you.  I am not affiliated with that site.  You apps android market url will be in the format

```
http://market.android.com/search?q=pname:<insert your AndroidManifest package here>
```

Answer (score 4):

Go to a place like http://qrcode.kaywa.com/ and enter your market url. For instance: market://details?id=com.company.product

Answer (score 2):

Go to [Android Market](https://market.android.com/) and find application. Check application URL for id paramater (e.g. "com.layar") and add use it in market link URL:

> `https://market.android.com/details?id=com.layar&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5sYXlhciJd`

For example, the following QR links to Android market Layar application using Google Chart API

[image]

```
<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=150x150&chl=market://search?q=pname:com.layar" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Google Charts API (http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/qr_codes.html).

Sample:

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=http://stackoverflow.com&choe=UTF-8

Comment: qrcode obsolete ?

Answer (score 0):

On the other note, search for your application on AndroidZoom.com or Androlib.com (Or on any other such bots), they might already have a QR Code created for your application.

Basically they, kinda, build a library of the apps of Android Market, so if your app is there, it will also have a QR code.